# Run-time error occurs when input value is greater than 100000

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the sieve of eratosthenes in C. The code works for small input values, but once the input goes beyond a certain range, a run- time error is thrown. This is the second problem in the classical section of the SPOJ base. What is the mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int prime(unsigned long int, unsigned long int);
int main()
{
    int nitem;
    unsigned long int sn,fn;
    scanf("%d", &nitem);
    while(nitem)
    {
        scanf("%lu", &fn);
        //printf("%d",fn);
        scanf("%lu", &sn);

        prime(fn, sn);
        nitem--;
    }
    return 0;
}

int prime(unsigned long int fn, unsigned long int sn)
{
    unsigned long int prim[100000];
    int i,j,k;
    for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        prim[i] = 1;
    }

    prim[0] = 0;
    prim[1] = 0;
    //printf("%d", sn);
    //printf("%d", k);
    //printf("%d", (k <= sn));
    for(k = 2; k <= sqrt(sn); k++)
    {
    //  printf("alksnc%5d", k);
        if(prim[k] == 1)
        {

            for(j = 2; (k * j) <= sn; j++)
            {
                //printf("%d", prim[k]);
                prim[k * j] = 0;

            }
        }
    }



    for(int i = 0; i <= sn; i++)
    {
        if(prim[i] !=0 && i >= fn)
        {
            printf("%lu\n", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
```

---

Input:

```
1
100000 100345
```

output:

```
run time error
```

Input:

```
1
3 5
```

output:

```
3
5
```

Comment: why [tag:java] and [tag:c++]?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This is a C program. It's not C++, and it's not Java. MikeCAT fixe it for you this time, but please remember for future.

Comment: Do not access out-of-range of array, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The error occurs on exactly which line?

Comment: Your title is grossly misleading. Your crashing sample input is `100000`, not `10000`.

Comment: You are passing `100345` to a function whoses array size is only `100000` and indexing with `prim[k * j] = 0;`. Your iteration limit is `(k * j) <= sn` but `sn >= 100000`. Allocate memory for the array according to the demands.

Comment: In the extreme case this `prim[k * j]` becomes `prim[sqrt(sn) * sn]`. `sqrt(sn) * sn` may not exceed `100000`, as per `unsigned long prim[100000];`. For `sn = 100000` this `sqrt(sn) * sn` definitely is `> 100000`.

Comment: @alk: There's the `for()`-loop condition to consider though. `for(j = 2; (k * j) <= sn; j++)`. Obviously there may be issues with integer overflow.

Comment: BTW for a sieve you don't need `unsigned long int prim[100000];` just `char prim[100000];` will do, or if you have very large numbers, a bit aray. Status is all that is needed.

Comment: @EOF: You are right. For whatever reasons I ignored the `(k *` :}

Comment: Hint: prepare the sieve once, based on the maximum limit stated in the SPOJ question. Otherwise you'll be very likely to hit a "time limit exceeded" failure. For this you'll be best to `calloc` a byte array and reverse the sense of your `0/1` status values.

Comment: I am sorry for multiple tags and making an error in the question. Won't happen again. @WeatherVane  yes, I was making an error indexing into the array, will try to re-implement it. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

We can make more efficient use of memory (2x) by only sieving odd numbers as all the even numbers you're processing waste time and space.  It's trickier to work out but gives us something like:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <libc.h>

#define MAX_ODD_PRIMES 1048576

void prime(unsigned long fn, unsigned long sn)
{
    unsigned char primes[MAX_ODD_PRIMES];

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < MAX_ODD_PRIMES; i++)
    {
        primes[i] = TRUE;
    }

    primes[0] = 0; // preset first odd, '1'

    for (unsigned long k = 3; k <= sqrt(sn) + 1; k += 2)
    {
        if (primes[k / 2])
        {
            for (unsigned long j = 3; (k * j) <= sn; j += 2)
            {
                primes[k * j / 2] = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fn <= 2)
    {
        printf("2\n");
        fn = 3;
    }

    for (unsigned long i = fn / 2; i * 2 + 1 <= sn; i++)
    {
        if (primes[i])
        {
            printf("%lu\n", i * 2 + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> ./a.out
1 1999900 2000000
1999957
1999969
1999979
1999993
>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Array range error.

By changing code

```
  for (j = 2; (k * j) <= sn; j++) {
    if (k * j >= 100000) {
      printf("Out of range %d %d\n", k, j);
      exit(1);
    }
    prim[k * j] = 0;

  }
}
```

With input 2, 100000
Output

```
Out of range 2 50000
```

By using an array (VLA) sized to the task, this is avoided.  Many other optimizations available.  Consider also a `malloc()` array.

```
void prime(unsigned long int fn, unsigned long int sn) {
  unsigned long int prim[sn + 1];
```

2) `int prime()` eventually performs `return;` where `return something;` is expected.  Suggest changing function to  `void prime()`

```
int prime(unsigned long int fn, unsigned long int sn) {
    unsigned long int prim[100000];
    ...
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```